# Problem using Boost with MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, build-process, mingw

We currently have some serious build problem because our client realized yesterday that he would require our library compiled with MinGW instead of VC++, deadline today. We have setup the toolchain, downloaded and built boost, all ran fine, everyting compiles and links. But even the simplest application using any of the compiled boost libraries will not run. gdb produces the infamous error:

```
Error: dll starting at 0x... not found
```

The thing is, that everything is linked statically. We suspect that there is some conflict with the runtime libraries, but we have no idea even how to diagnose the error more precisely. We have built everything with the same compiler (GCC 4.5 comming with MinGW). Applications that do not use compiled boost libraries run fine.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: What happens when you run your application without GDB?

Comment: We get a pop-up error message saying something like *Could not run the application (0x0000005)*. It's German, so I do not know what exactly the corresponding English error is.

Comment: Is this problem solved? I'd like to know the solution too.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I have some questions that might help you onto right track. Is it 32 bit application? Are you trying to run it on Win64 or Win32?  Do you have an idea what DLL this is that is missing? You could try  ["Dependency Walker"](http://www.dependencywalker.com) which might help to figure that out.

Comment: Dependency walker shows no problems. All systems and compilers involved are 32 bit.

Comment: Did you use dependency walker on gdb.exe. It sounds like that tool is missing a dll, so you can not debug with it.